# Form and case properties not being saved when testing in a future date

Tags: commcare

I'm testing a form in Commcare that only shows up when today is less than a date saved into the case (date_next_reset)

To make the form appear, I change the phone date to 1 day after that date_next_reset.

The module shows fine, but the date_next_reset case property that is supposed to get updated (for the first day othe next month) inside of the same form is not getting updated.

When checking the case list, CommCare is not even showing that the form was fullfilled.

I checked all filters and dates that are supposed to be saved and seems fine (was working before) but not it isn't.

I'm wondering if something can happen when working with future dates changed in the phone.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the date on the phone should not have any effect on CommCare's form/case processing apart from the `now()` and `today()` functions used in forms. It sounds like there is a different issue going on with your application but seems unlikely caused by the date change and more likely to be a bug in the underlying application logic or in the data somehow.